# Single Sign On - ASP.net Website and Desktop Application

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm currently implementing a single signon so that users from a desktop application can log into the website related to that application without re-entering account credentials.

I looked over the following link, and I implement it very similar to the 'Accepted Solution'.

[Enabling single sign-on between Desktop Application and Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81423/enabling-single-sign-on-between-desktop-application-and-website)

The implementation does however currently rely on a 'shared secret', an access key that is shared between the 2 programs.

I like'd Andreas Petersson's approach of making a hash out of salting the password and combining that with the token to increase security, but the desktop application does not have access to the password.  For the desktop application my code is implemented as a DLL that is loaded automatically and has access to the application data only through an API (It's not able to communicate directly with the database).

Any suggestions on the proper way to do this?

My thought was to use a randomly generated long number stored in the code of both applications, and hash that with the current date, and passing the resultant hash as the access code to allow a token to be generated.